# How do I bring back the ribbon in Office 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office-2010, ribbon

The ribbon in Excel 2010 appears when I click on Home or Insert or one of the other tabs, but disappears again when I go back to editing my document. I'd like it to always be visible - how can I get it back so that it stays there?

Not sure whether the correct term for it would be "minimized", "hidden" or something else, but it's gone until I click a tab heading.

Comment: I commend you for editing to match the MS Office spelling.. it hurt me too to use a 'z' ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on one of the tab headings and uncheck `Minimize the Ribbon`.

[[image: Screenshot of menu option]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orepc.png)

Comment: For folks that like keyboard shortcuts this is also controlable via the combo 'Ctrl + F1'

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Bob's answer, there's a little icon in the upper-right corner.  It's to the left of the question mark in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If using VBA code, insert this line to hide it:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
```

To unhide it, use:

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
```

Comment: Remember to properly format your question. Use a right angle bracket `>` before each line of a block quote, and indent code blocks with four spaces